# How to use \ref to refer to a \label in another document?

Tags: texworks, auxiliary-files, xr

I have two documents and am trying to use the package `xr` to create a reference, in the second document, to a `\label` in the first. But `??` appears in the PDF instead. How do I enable the second to see the first's `\labels`?

Minimal example:

`xr2a.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A}\label{a}
\end{document}
```

`xr2b.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{xr2a}
\begin{document}
\ref{a}
\end{document}
```

I am using pdfLaTeX and TeXworks.

The files are in the same directory.

I don't want hyperlinks.

There is very little in the `xr` package's documentation -- have I used it correctly?

Some similar older questions on the same topic have got answers which say that `xr` needs to read the `.aux` file. pdfLaTeX lately runs OK without any `.aux` files. Does `xr` still need to read the `.aux` file nowadays? If so, how do I get TeXworks to get pdfLaTeX to a) keep the `.aux` file b) revert to the default behaviour of not keeping an `.aux` file?

Comment: I am confused. Surely, the default behaviour is keeping the `.aux` file? Without it, even internal cross references don't work. Anyhow, the example works for me.

Comment: If pdfLaTeX runs and makes a `.pdf`, only the `.tex`, `.synctex.gz` and `.pdf` remain. I might have changed a setting, but nothing in TeXworks's Edit\Preferences menus seem relevant. The default with my installation has been to delete the `.aux`, since 15 Jun 2018. Behaviour sometimes changes automatically because a new version automatically installs itself. Internal cross-references within a document work fine.

Comment: Just to clarify: It is definitely not the default behaviour of pdfLaTeX (or any other LaTeX engine) to clean up the `.aux` files after itself. It must be a setting of your editor or your compilation tool (if you use that). The `.aux` file is required not only to get cross references with `xr` right, but also to be able to produce proper cross references within the document.

Comment: latex needs the aux file always whether or not you use `xr` otherwise no references or table of contents or lists of tables etc  will work.

Comment: Eureka. I will explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As David Carlisle pointed out, TeX engines need to write `.aux` files. So, XY problem, the Y now being "How do I stop the automatic deletion of the `.aux` file after a successful run?". I use TeXworks, and the solution in my case is: when using TeXworks to make a document containing `\label`s to which other documents `\ref`er, select the compilation mode `pdfLaTeX` (not `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`). I had been using the compilation mode `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` -- presumably MakeIndex or BibTeX cleans up the `.aux` and `.log` files if the run succeeded. As moewe says, the pdfLaTeX phase does not delete those files, so it must be one of the later phases.

Comment: Unless you changed something I cannot imagine that any of those compilation combinations in TeXworks include doing a full cleanup. As these are usually only neededif something goes really wrong

Comment: If you are using MikTeX `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` runs `texify`. Usually `texify` should not delete `.aux` files after a successful run, but there is an option to enable that (`-c`). So maybe check your configurations that the `-c` is not included.